# Module is shown as installed but I can't access its settings

Tags: 7

I have Drupal 7 installed and I am trying to install Webform module. Firstly the page shows " The website has faced some unexpected error" and then after re-accessing the Modules page, it shows the Module to be enabled and links to it's settings as well.

But when I go to Create Content, I don't see any Webform option.

This is the error generated in the Reports / Log.

> DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Table webform already exists. in DatabaseSchema->createTable() (line 657 of /home/evosysgr/public_html/includes/database/schema.inc).

Kindly suggest what is to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Generic way when you face

> The website has faced some unexpected error

when enabling module is:

1. Find in logs what error was it
2. Fix it's cause
3. Disable and uninstall module you was enabling
4. Enable it again

Alternatively, if you have backups, **better** way would be:

1. Find in logs what error was it
2. Fix it's cause
3. Restore site from backup to it's state from just before error
4. Try again

If you have *specific* problem with this way, ask new question, explaining exactly what you need to know, what you did, what was in logs and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, As I mentioned,following is the error generated in the Reports / Log : DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Table webform already exists. in DatabaseSchema->createTable() (line 657 of /home/evosysgr/public_html/includes/database/schema.inc).  Also I tried disabling  & enabling but it didn't work as well. Also not sure about the state of the previous backups as lots of done ( on content & custom content types has been done already).

Comment: @GaurangAgarwal No no no, I'm talking about error that happened during your very first attempt to install this module. Error you keep posting looks like merely a result, aftershock. Oh, and disabling without **uninstall** cannot help.

Comment: #Molot - If I will uninstall the module then again if I will install it, will it help ? As I couldn't locate the log of first instance of installation of Webform.

Comment: I'm not a fairy, I can't tell future. It has a pretty good chance to help. But will it? Why don't you try and tell us?